# Ajax Jquery serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax and JQuery serialize to submit a form. However, for textarea and text box items, if the user data contains < and > the form will not submit. I expect the serialize does not work correctly because it interprets these characters as HTML.

How do I handle text box and textarea elements if the user enters < and >?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your current code as a [mcve]. It will be much easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode HTML before pass your content value to serialize and then to decode the value. Like this:

```
function EncodeHtml(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function DecodeHtml(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

[JSfiddle DEMO... try ENCODE and then DECODE buttons](https://jsfiddle.net/rxhux3vs/)